# JCEF - CefInitializer jawt.dll already loaded - MAVEN

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to use JCEF in my application. I'm working with SpringBoot. See my source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplicationBuilder springBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringbootJcefScaffoldApplication.class);
    springBuilder.headless(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = springBuilder.run(args);
    /* Run JCEF application in its own thread*/
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Create a new CefAppBuilder instance
            CefAppBuilder cefBuilder = new CefAppBuilder();
            //Configure the builder instance
            cefBuilder.setInstallDir(new File("jcef-bundle")); //Default
            cefBuilder.setProgressHandler(new ConsoleProgressHandler()); //Default
            cefBuilder.getCefSettings().windowless_rendering_enabled = true; //Default - select OSR mode
            // Windowed rendering mode is used by default. If you want to test OSR mode set |useOsr| to true and recompile.
            boolean useOsr = false;
            try {
                new MainFrame("http://localhost:8080", useOsr, false, args);
            } catch (UnsupportedPlatformException | CefInitializationException | IOException
                    | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

I'm doing a very basic test with the browser, trying to open a URL on my localhost. However, when running spring boot I am having the following problems:

```
2024-01-28 10:29:53.524  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : DOWNLOADING |> 97.0
2024-01-28 10:29:53.538  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : DOWNLOADING |> 98.0
2024-01-28 10:29:53.551  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : DOWNLOADING |> 99.0
2024-01-28 10:29:53.625  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : DOWNLOADING |> 100.0
2024-01-28 10:29:53.625  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : EXTRACTING |> In progress...
2024-01-28 10:29:56.017  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : INSTALL |> In progress...
2024-01-28 10:29:56.017  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : INITIALIZING |> In progress...
2024-01-28 10:29:56.020  WARN 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.impl.step.init.CefInitializer      : Error while loading jawt library: Native Library C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin\jawt.dll already loaded in another classloader
2024-01-28 10:29:56.183  INFO 6516 --- [       Thread-8] m.f.j.i.progress.ConsoleProgressHandler  : INITIALIZED |> In progress...
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path C:\WINDOWS\system32
[0128/102956.242:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.243:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[0128/102956.245:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.245:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0128/102956.253:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.253:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[0128/102956.254:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.254:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 4 time(s)
[0128/102956.255:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.255:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[0128/102956.255:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.255:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
[0128/102956.256:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.256:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 7 time(s)
[0128/102956.257:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.257:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 8 time(s)
[0128/102956.257:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(973)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=0
[0128/102956.257:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1292)] The GPU process has crashed 9 time(s)
[0128/102956.257:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(417)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

Well, I've seen some reports saying to change the JCEF project within CefApp.java there is a way to add a try catch, but as I'm using Maven I'm not seeing a better solution for this case, as I can't change one class of a dependency. Does anyone see any solution for this?

> Detail: I've already tried downloading the JCEF sources, building them
> on my computer with visual studio code, but I ended up having numerous
> problems that I couldn't solve when running the make_distrib.bat win64
> command. I followed all the procedures as shown here:
> https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md
> but it didn't work, and honestly I would like to be able to run JCEF
> via Maven, I believe there must be some way , but I can't